# Laravel 5.2 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT

Tags: laravel, redirect, middleware

I have a project I developed with Laravel.I did not receive "localhost" while I was working, but after transferring it to hosting I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT" error.There's no place for error at any moment.Now, My YoneticiKontrol middleware ;

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class YoneticiKontrol { 
    /** 
     * Handle an incoming request. * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request 
     * @param \Closure $next 
     * @return mixed 
    */ 

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) { 
        if($request->session()->get('yoneticiRutbe')) { 
            return $next($request); 
        }else{ 
            return redirect('/'); 
        }
    }
}
```

My OturumKontrolu middleware

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OturumKontrolu
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->get('yoneticiSifre') && $request->session()->get('yoneticiMail')){
            return redirect('/anakumanda');
        }else{
            return $next($request);
        }

    }
}
```

My Route

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

use App\Http\Middleware\OturumKontrolu;
use App\Http\Middleware\YoneticiKontrol;

Route::get('/','anasayfa\indexController@index');
Route::get('/cikis','anakumanda\yoneticiGiris@cik')->name('yoneticiCikis');

/*Oturum Kontrolü yapan devre*/
Route::group(['middleware'=>OturumKontrolu::class],function(){
    Route::get('/anakumandaGiris','anakumanda\yoneticiGiris@index')->name('yoneticiGiris');
    Route::post('/anakumandaGiris','anakumanda\yoneticiGiris@store')->name('yoneticiKontrol');

});



/*Yönetici Kontrolü yapan devre*/
    Route::group(['middleware'=>[YoneticiKontrol::class]],function(){
    //Yönetici Rota İşlemleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda','yoneticiController@show');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniYonetici','yoneticiController@index')->name('yoneticiEkleSayfasi');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniYoneticiEkle','yoneticiController@store')->name('yoneticiEklemeSayfasi');

    //Sınıf Rota işlemleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniSinif','sinifController@index')->name('sinifEkleSayfasi');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniSinifEkle','sinifController@store')->name('sinifEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleSinif/{id?}','sinifController@edit')->name('SinifDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenSinif/{id?}/edit','sinifController@update')->name('sinifguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silSinif/{id?}','sinifController@destroy')->name('sinifsil');
    //Ders Rota İşlemleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniDers','DersController@index')->name('dersEkleSayfasi');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniDersEkle','DersController@store')->name('dersEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleDers/{id?}','DersController@edit')->name('DersDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenDers/{id?}/edit','DersController@update')->name('dersguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silDers/{id?}','DersController@destroy')->name('derssil');
    //Konu Rota İşlemleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniKonu','KonuController@index')->name('konuEkleSayfasi');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-dersSecCek/{id?}','KonuController@show')->name('dersSecCek');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniKonuEkle','KonuController@store')->name('konuEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleKonu/{id?}','KonuController@edit')->name('KonuDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenKonu/{id?}/edit','KonuController@update')->name('konuguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silKonu/{id?}','KonuController@destroy')->name('konusil');
    //Konu Rota İşlemleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniKazanim','KazanimController@index')->name('kazanimEkleSayfasi');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-konuSecCek/{id?}','KazanimController@show')->name('kazanimdersSecCek');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniKazanimEkle','KazanimController@store')->name('kazanimEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleKazanim/{id?}','KazanimController@edit')->name('KonuDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenKazanim/{id?}/edit','KazanimController@update')->name('kazanimguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silKazanim/{id?}','KazanimController@destroy')->name('kazanimsil');
    //Soru Tipi Girişleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniSoruTipi','SoruTipleriController@index')->name('soruTipiSayfa');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniSoruTipiEkle','SoruTipleriController@store')->name('soruTipiEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleSoruTipi/{id?}','SoruTipleriController@edit')->name('SoruTipiDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenSoruTipi/{id?}/edit','SoruTipleriController@update')->name('sorutipiguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silSoruTipi/{id?}','SoruTipleriController@destroy')->name('soruTipisil');
    //Soru Çeşidi Girişleri
    Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniSoruCesidi','SoruCesidiController@index')->name('soruCesidiSayfa');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniSoruCesidiEkle','SoruCesidiController@store')->name('soruCesidiEklemeSayfasi');
    Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleSoruCesidi/{id?}','SoruCesidiController@edit')->name('SoruCesidiDuzenleme');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenSoruCesidi/{id?}/edit','SoruCesidiController@update')->name('sorucesidiguncelle');
    Route::post('/anakumanda-silSoruCesidi/{id?}','SoruCesidiController@destroy')->name('soruCesidinisil');

        //Ölçü Girişleri Girişleri
     Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniOlcu','OlcuTipleriController@index')->name('olcuTipiÇeşitleri');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniOlcuEkle','OlcuTipleriController@store')->name('olcuEklemeSayfasi');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleOlcu/{id?}','OlcuTipleriController@edit')->name('OlcuTipDuzenleme');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenOlcu/{id?}/edit','OlcuTipleriController@update')->name('olcucesidiguncelle');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-silOlcu/{id?}','OlcuTipleriController@destroy')->name('olcuCesidinisil');
        //Şık Tipi Girişleri Girişleri
     Route::get('/anakumanda-yeniSik','SikTipleriController@index')->name('sikTipiÇeşitleri');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniSikEkle','SikTipleriController@store')->name('sikEklemeSayfasi');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleSik/{id?}','SikTipleriController@edit')->name('sikTipDuzenleme');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenSik/{id?}/edit','SikTipleriController@update')->name('sikcesidiguncelle');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-silSik/{id?}','SikTipleriController@destroy')->name('sikCesidinisil');
        //Test Hazırlama
     Route::get('/anakumanda-testHazirla','ilkoSoru@index')->name('yonetimPaneli');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-tipSecCek/{id?}','ilkoSoru@tipSec')->name('tipSecCek');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-ham-soru','ilkoSoru@testHamSoru')->name('hamSoru');

     Route::get('/anakumanda-paragraf-oncul','ilkoSoru@testParagrafOncul')->name('paragrafOncul');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-siralama-oncul','ilkoSoru@testListeOncul')->name('listeOncul');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-gorsel-oncul','ilkoSoru@testGorselOncul')->name('gorselOncul');

     Route::get('/anakumanda-ortak-liste-oncul','ilkoSoru@testOrtakListe')->name('ortakListe');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-ortak-paragraf-oncul','ilkoSoru@testOrtakParagraf')->name('ortakListe');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-ortak-gorsel-oncul','ilkoSoru@testOrtakGorsel')->name('ortakGorsel');

     Route::post('/anakumanda-kazanimSecCek/{id?}','ilkoSoru@kazanimCek')->name('kazanimCek');

        //Soru Giriş Rotaları
     Route::post('/anakumanda-yeniHamSoru','TestSorulariController@store')->name('hamSoruEkle');
     Route::get('/anakumanda-guncelleHamSoru/{id?}','TestSorulariController@edit')->name('hamSoruDuzenleme');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-duzenHamSoru/{id?}/edit','TestSorulariController@update')->name('HamSoruguncelle');
     Route::post('/anakumanda-silHamSoru/{id?}','TestSorulariController@destroy')->name('hamSoruSil');

        //Soru İzlem Sayfaları
      Route::get('/anakumanda-onayBekleyenTest','TestSorulariController@onayBekleyenTest')->name('onaybekleyen');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-redEdilenTest','TestSorulariController@redEdilenTest')->name('rededilen');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-onaylananTest','TestSorulariController@onaylananTest')->name('onaylanan');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-grafikOnayTest','TestSorulariController@grafikTest')->name('grafikonaylanan');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-onayimiBekleyenTest','TestSorulariController@onayimiBekleyenTest')->name('onayimibekleyen');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-grafikOnayimiBekleyenTest','TestSorulariController@grafikOnayimiBekleyenTest')->name('grafikonayimibekleyen');
      Route::get('/anakumanda-onayIslemleriTestSorulari/{id?}','TestSorulariController@show')->name('onayIslembekleyen');
      Route::post('/anakumanda-onaylaHamSoru/{id?}','TestSorulariController@onayla')->name('hamSoruOnayla');
      Route::post('/anakumanda-reddetHamSoru/{id?}','TestSorulariController@reddet')->name('hamSoruReddet');

});



Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

If I need another place my post. Thank you.

Comment: You are redirecting to `anakumanda` but I cannot see this in your routes

Comment: Route::get('/anakumanda','anasayfa\indexController@index'); I used Except for "middleware".

Comment: Could you please edit the question and show us WHERE the `anakumanda` route is defined?

Comment: I led it to the homepage. My homepage route has been added.

Comment: You now have 2 snippets of Routes, which is making your question even more confusing

Comment: I'm editing right away

Comment: I guess error is here ( if($request->session()->get('yoneticiRutbe')) { 
            return $next($request); } ). You get into a cycle and get  "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT"

Comment: @OdinThunder how to edit?